# Hiding SVG elements takes so much time

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, svg

I'm trying to show/hide some svg elements. My svg is kind of huge. In order to show or hide, it takes like 8 seconds for doing that. I would really like having it in less time. It is about 1996 elements (don't think it is to much for that time). Therefore, I think my code is not the best one. I hope you can help me optimizing that code.

```
isChecked = jqElement.is(':checked');
type = jqElement.attr('tag');
var start = new Date().getTime();
elements = document.getElementsByClassName(type);
console.log('LAYER ' + type + ': ' + elements.length);
for (j=0; j<elements.length; j++)
    elements[j].setAttribute('visibility', (isChecked)? '' : 'hidden');
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
console.log('Execution time for layer ' + type + ': '+ time);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are all of the SVG elements inside some common container?  If so, you could try manipulating the container's visibility instead of each individual element's.  Alternately, can you manipulate the style rules for the class and let the browser worry about applying the new rules to everything?

Comment: how do you accomplish the second option?

Comment: @Ruben Not sure.  I assume that there's a way to manipulate stylesheets at runtime, but I've never tried to do so.

Comment: If you ask another question I can answer that.

Comment: @RobertLongson uhmm what do you mean with another question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and I'll tell you how to manipulate style rules if that's what you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302796/how-can-i-manipulate-css-into-a-svg